# Не найдена MainActivity при запуске приложения

Tags: android

Ошибка:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 15792
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myapplication.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.myapplication/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~MLpIwGCY6RSRZIKRrMWiyw==/com.example.myapplication-J4jT2nUW2tbuPEyOPHd9qg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~MLpIwGCY6RSRZIKRrMWiyw==/com.example.myapplication-J4jT2nUW2tbuPEyOPHd9qg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3582)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3813)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2308)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7893)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myapplication.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.myapplication/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~MLpIwGCY6RSRZIKRrMWiyw==/com.example.myapplication-J4jT2nUW2tbuPEyOPHd9qg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~MLpIwGCY6RSRZIKRrMWiyw==/com.example.myapplication-J4jT2nUW2tbuPEyOPHd9qg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1334)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3569)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3813) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2308) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7893) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

W/System: A resource failed to call close.

Comment: А он есть у вас такой класс `com.example.myapplication.MainActivity`? Именно в таком пакете он расположен?

Comment: @Roma, приложите в вопрос содержимое файла `AndroidManifest.xml`. Возможно, вы забыли указать в манифесте флаг `exported=true` для вашей активити. Отредактировать вопрос можно, нажав на кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1471545/edit).